# Sum count of sessions with Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, kibana

I have a issue with the sum aggregation in Kibana.

My usecase is that each of my servers periodically reports the number of open sessions. In Kibana, I want to visualize the total count of all sessions across all servers. But even if only one server is online that has one session, the count is wrong (it is higher). The reason for this is that Elasticsearch sums all values of a given time bucket. So if I report every 10 seconds and thethe interval is 1 minute seconds, Kibana shows 6 as the session count.

[image: Kibana sum aggregation]

One way would be to manually set the interval to to the reporting interval (10s in this example).

[image: Kibana date histogram interval]

Another way is to scale the values via a script (divide them by 6):
[image: Kibana script]

But both approaches are quite hacky and require knowledge of the reporting interval. If one decides afterwards to report more or less frequently the graph is wrong again.

Does someone know of a better solution?

**Edit**:

I could add a sub-bucket and split lines by server, but my data model is slightly more complex. I use multiple tags to distinguish a server. I'm currently using the tags `application` `host` and `instance`. On one host, there can be multiple instances of the same application. A instance can be something like `test`, `dev`, `integration-test`, `prod`, …. One particular instance can be deployed on different hosts. For example `prod` might be clustered over multiple hosts. So I'd at least have to split by host and instance to show correct results for one application but that is not possible in kibana. Also, additional tags could be added in the future like `datacenter`, `region`, …

**Edit 2**

This is an example datapoint:

```
{
    "name": "http_sessions",
    "application": "My Application",
    "host": "My Host",
    "instance": "Loadtest",
    "count": 21
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your data structure - could you include a an example of a few data points?

Comment: I've added a example datapoint in Edit 2

Comment: One possibility would be to have a `"series": "..."` property that either contains a hash or a comma separated list of all tag values (like `name`, `application`, `host`). Then I could use a `avg` aggregation on `count` and add a bucket with a `terms` aggregation on `series` and have the values stacked. But actually I don't want to have multiple stacked graphs (or areas). Especially if the legend of those graphs contain very long comma separated tag values or even unreadable hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the average aggregation and then multiply it by the number of servers.

Comment: It can be hard to know the exact number of servers. Especially if you are scaling according to the load of your application. Even if the number of servers is relatively static, some servers could be down. For example when they have crashed or during rolling deployments.